# biblatex problem - year dropped from only one citation for some reason

Tags: biblatex

Good day.

Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % needed for including graphics e.g. EPS, PS
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-3cm}
\topmargin -0.5cm        % read Lamport p.163
\oddsidemargin -0.04cm   % read Lamport p.163
\evensidemargin -0.04cm  % same as oddsidemargin but for left-hand pages
\textwidth 16.59cm
\textheight 21.94cm
%\captionsetup[table]{font=bf,position=below}
%\captionsetup[figure]{font=bf}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true, url=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
    urlseen = {Accessed on},
  }
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother
\bibliography{turkeybanking}
\nocite{*}
\usepackage{url}
%\pagestyle{empty}       % Uncomment if don't want page numbers
\parskip 7.2pt           % sets spacing between paragraphs
\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.6}    % Uncomment for 1.5 spacing between lines
%\linespread{2}
\parindent 0cm        % sets leading space for paragraphs
```

My problem is strange. I have a list of 45 citations in my biblatex file. When I do a quickbuild in TexMaker, whatever the 36th citation is, the year is dropped in the reference list and the intext citation becomes author (title) instead of author (year). If I change the order of the references in my biblatex file, the problem jumps to a new reference. But for some reason it is always the 36th reference that has the problem. Everything before and after is fine.

I also have another tex file that uses the same preamble and the same biblatex file and everything works fine. I know this sounds a bit odd and I am a bit of a LaTeX neophyte, but if anyone can give me some help, I would appreciate it.

UPDATE
Take the following document as an example:

```
\begin{document}

\textcite{altunbas2009turkish}, \textcite{assunccao2013eliminating},
\textcite{baer2000privatization}, \textcite{beck2005state},
\textcite{biglaiser2004expansion}, \textcite{blyth2002great},
\textcite{bongini2009emerging}, \textcite{calomiris2011fragile},
\textcite{cizre2005turkish}, \textcite{de2003globalization},
\textcite{demello2012bye}, \textcite{epstein2013foreign},
\textcite{garman2001fiscal}, \textcite{gerschenkron1962economic},
\textcite{haggard1995financial}, \textcite{hutchcroft1998booty},
\textcite{kohli2004state}, \textcite{levy2004should},
\textcite{lukauskas2000explaining}, \textcite{marois2011emerging},
\textcite{martinez2003financial}, \textcite{martinez2009globalizing},
\textcite{maxfield1991bankers}, \textcite{montinola2003recovers},
\textcite{mukherjee2013candidate}, \textcite{ogura2002banking},
\textcite{onder2010banks}, \textcite{onics1998state},
\textcite{onics2009beyond}, \textcite{paula2011regulation},
\textcite{pepinsky2009openness}, \textcite{rodriguez2008banking},
\textcite{satyanath2006globalization}, \textcite{taylor2009institutional},
\textcite{thebanker2013regionalbanks}, \textcite{thebanker2013riding},
\textcite{thies2009politics}, \textcite{treisman2004stabilization},
\textcite{verdier2000rise}, \textcite{von2010federal},
\textcite{wade1990governing}, \textcite{wellons1985international},
\textcite{winters1994power}, \textcite{zhang2004changing},
\textcite{zysman1983governments}

\begin{spacing}{1.15}

\printbibliography

\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

And here is my corresponding .bib file:

```
@article{rodriguez2008banking,
title={Banking on democracy: The political economy of international private bank lending in emerging markets},
author={Rodr{\'\i}guez, Javier and Santiso, Javier},
journal={International Political Science Review},
volume={29},
number={2},
pages={215--246},
year={2008},
}

@article{montinola2003recovers,
title={Who recovers first? Banking crises resolution in developing countries},
author={Montinola, Gabriella R},
journal={Comparative Political Studies},
volume={36},
number={5},
pages={541--574},
year={2003},
}

@article{verdier2000rise,
title={The rise and fall of state banking in OECD countries},
author={Verdier, Daniel},
journal={Comparative Political Studies},
volume={33},
number={3},
pages={283--318},
year={2000},
}

@book{gerschenkron1962economic,
title={Economic backwardness in historical perspective},
author={Gerschenkron, Alexander},
year={1962},
publisher={Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press}
}

@book{haggard1995financial,
title={Financial systems and economic policy in developing countries},
author={Haggard, Stephan and Lee, Chung H},
year={1995},
publisher={Ithaca, NY.: Cornell University Press}
}

@article{de2003globalization,
title={Globalization and recent political transitions in Brazil},
author={De Castro, Marcus Faro and De Carvalho, Maria Izabel Vallad{\~a}o},
journal={International Political Science Review},
volume={24},
number={4},
pages={465--490},
year={2003},
}

@article{maxfield1991bankers,
title={Bankers' Alliances and Economic Policy Patterns Evidence from Mexico and Brazil},
author={Maxfield, Sylvia},
journal={Comparative Political Studies},
volume={23},
number={4},
pages={419--458},
year={1991},
}

@article{martinez2003financial,
title={Financial markets and politics: The confidence game in Latin American emerging economies},
author={Martinez, Juan and Santiso, Javier},
journal={International Political Science Review},
volume={24},
number={3},
pages={363--395},
year={2003},
}

@article{taylor2009institutional,
title={Institutional development through policy-making: a case study of the Brazilian Central Bank},
author={Taylor, Matthew M},
journal={World Politics},
volume={61},
number={3},
pages={487--515},
year={2009},
}

@article{marois2011emerging,
title={Emerging market bank rescues in an era of finance-led neoliberalism: A comparison of Mexico and Turkey},
author={Marois, Thomas},
journal={Review of International Political Economy},
volume={18},
number={2},
pages={168--196},
year={2011},
}

@article{thies2009politics,
title={The Politics of Exchange Rate-Based Stabilization Versus Structural Reforms in Latin America},
author={Thies, Cameron G and Arce, Moises},
journal={Comparative Political Studies},
volume={42},
number={9},
pages={1193--1216},
year={2009},
}

@article{biglaiser2004expansion,
title={The expansion of neoliberal economic reforms in Latin America},
author={Biglaiser, Glen and DeRouen, Karl},
journal={International Studies Quarterly},
volume={48},
number={3},
pages={561--578},
year={2004},
}

@article{lukauskas2000explaining,
title={Explaining styles of financial market opening in Chile, Mexico, South Korea, and Turkey},
author={Lukauskas, Arvid and Minushkin, Susan},
journal={International Studies Quarterly},
volume={44},
number={4},
pages={695--723},
year={2000},
}

@article{garman2001fiscal,
title={Fiscal decentralization: A political theory with Latin American cases},
author={Garman, Christopher and Haggard, Stephan and Willis, Eliza},
journal={World Politics},
volume={53},
number={2},
pages={205--236},
year={2001},
}

@article{winters1994power,
title={Power and the Control of Capital},
author={Winters, Jeffrey A},
journal={World Politics},
volume={46},
number={3},
pages={419--52},
year={1994},
}

@article{cizre2005turkish,
title={The Turkish encounter with neo-liberalism: economics and politics in the 2000/2001 crises},
author={Cizre, {\"U}mit and Yeldan, Erin{\c{c}}},
journal={Review of International Political Economy},
volume={12},
number={3},
pages={387--408},
year={2005},
}

@article{onics2009beyond,
title={Beyond the 2001 financial crisis: The political economy of the new phase of neo-    liberal restructuring in Turkey},
author={{\"O}ni{\c{s}}, Ziya},
journal={Review of International Political Economy},
volume={16},
number={3},
pages={409--432},
year={2009},
}

@article{mukherjee2013candidate,
title={Candidate-centred systems, public banks and equity market restrictions in developing democracies},
author={Mukherjee, Bumba and Yadav, Vineeta and Bejar, Sergio},
journal={Review of International Political Economy},
number={forthcoming},
pages={1--40},
year={2013},
}

@article{pepinsky2009openness,
title={Openness without Liberalization: Why Bankers in Emerging Markets Support Financial Internationalization},
author={Pepinsky, Thomas B},
journal={Review of International Political Economy},
number={forthcoming},
year={2013},
}

@article{epstein2013foreign,
title={When do foreign banks 'cut and run'? Evidence from west European bailouts and east European markets},
author={Epstein, Rachel A},
journal={Review of International Political Economy},
number={forthcoming},
pages={1--31},
year={2013},
}

@article{assunccao2013eliminating,
title={Eliminating entry barriers for the provision of banking services: evidence from 'banking correspondents' in Brazil},
author={Assun{\c{c}}ao, Juliano},
volume = {37},
pages = {2806-2811},
journal={Journal of Banking \& Finance},
year={2013},
}

@article{beck2005state,
title={State bank transformation in Brazil--choices and consequences},
author={Beck, Thorsten and Crivelli, Juan Miguel and Summerhill, William},
journal={Journal of Banking \& finance},
volume={29},
number={8},
pages={2223--2257},
year={2005},
}

@article{baer2000privatization,
title={Privatization and restructuring of banks in Brazil},
author={Baer, Werner and Nazmi, Nader},
journal={The Quarterly Review of Economics and Finance},
volume={40},
number={1},
pages={3--24},
year={2000},
}

@article{demello2012bye,
title={Bye, bye financial repression, hello financial deepening: The anatomy of a financial boom},
author={De Mello, Jo{\~a}o Manoel P and Garcia, M{\'a}rcio GP},
journal={The Quarterly Review of Economics and Finance},
volume={52},
number={2},
pages={135--153},
year={2012},
}

@article{treisman2004stabilization,
title={Stabilization tactics in Latin America: Menem, Cardoso, and the politics of low inflation},
author={Treisman, Daniel},
journal={Comparative Politics},
pages={399--419},
year={2004},
}

@book{zysman1983governments,
title={Governments, markets, and growth: financial systems and the politics of industrial change},
author={Zysman, John},
year={1983},
publisher={Ithaca, NY.: Cornell University Press}
}

@article{calomiris2011fragile,
title={Fragile Banks, Durable Bargains: Why Banking is All about Politics and Always Had Been},
author={Calomiris, Charles and Haber, Stephen},
journal={Book manuscript in progress},
year={forthcoming}
}

@article{levy2004should,
title={Should the government be in the banking business? The role of state-owned and development banks},
author={Levy-Yeyati, Eduardo and Micco, Alejandro and Panizza, Ugo},
year={2004},
publisher={Research Working Paper \#517. Inter-American Development Bank}
}

@article{onder2010banks,
title={Banks, regional development disparity and growth: evidence from Turkey},
author={{\"O}nder, Zeynep and {\"O}zy{\i}ld{\i}r{\i}m, S{\"u}heyla},
journal={Cambridge journal of economics},
volume={34},
number={6},
pages={975--1000},
year={2010},
}

@book{martinez2009globalizing,
title={Globalizing in Hard Times: The Politics of Banking-Sector Opening in the Emerging World},
author={Martinez-Diaz, Leonardo},
year={2009},
publisher={Cornell University Press}
}

@book{blyth2002great,
title={Great Transformations: Economic Ideas and Institutional Change in the Tewntieth Century},
author={Blyth, Mark},
year={2002},
publisher={Cambridge, Mass.: Cambridge University Press}
}

@InCollection{paula2011regulation,
author = {{de Paula}, Luiz Fernando and Sobreira, Rog{\'e}rio},
title = {The 2008 Financial Crisis and Banking Regulation in Brazil},
booktitle = {An Assessment of the Global Impact of the Financial Crisis},
OPTcrossref = {crossref},
OPTkey = {key},
publisher = {Basingstoke: Palgrave Macmillan},
year = {2011},
editor = {Arestis, Philip and Sobreira, Rog{\'e}rio and Oreiro, Jos{\'e} Luis},
}


@book{onics1998state,
title={State and market: The political economy of Turkey in comparative perspective},
author={{\"O}ni{\c{s}}, Ziya},
year={1998},
publisher={Bo{\u{g}}azi{\c{c}}i University Press Istanbul},
}

@article{wellons1985international,
title={International debt: the behavior of banks in a politicized environment},
author={Wellons, Philip A},
journal={International Organization},
pages={441--471},
year={1985},
}

@book{bongini2009emerging,
title={Emerging Banking Systems},
author={Bongini, Paola Agnese and Chiarlone, Stefano and Ferri, Giovanni},
year = {2009},
publisher={Palgrave Macmillan}
}

@book{von2010federal,
title={Federal banking in Brazil: Policies and competitive advantages},
author={Von Mettenheim, Kurt E},
year={2010},
publisher={Pickering \& Chatto Publishers}
}

@book{hutchcroft1998booty,
title={Booty Capitalism: The Politics of the Banking in the Philippines},
author={Hutchcroft, Paul David},
year={1998},
publisher={Ithaca, NY: Cornell University Press},
}

@article{thebanker2013regionalbanks,
author={Cooper,Jane},
year={March 2013},
month={March},
title={Report: International banking operations - Supra-regional banks - Emerging markets take hold in the developing world},
journal={The Banker}, 
}

@article{thebanker2013riding,
author={Rumsey, John},
year={March 1, 2013},
title={Americas: Brazil - Banking - Riding out the storm},
journal={The Banker}, 
}

@book{ogura2002banking,
title={Banking, the state, and industrial promotion in developing Japan, 1900-73},
author= {Ogura, Shinji},
year={2002},
publisher={Palgrave Macmillan: United Kingdom}
}

@book{altunbas2009turkish,
title={Turkish Banking: Banking Under Political Instability and Chronic High Inflation},
author={Altunbas, Yener and Kara, Alper and Olgu, Ozlem},
year={2009},
publisher={Palgrave Macmillan: United Kingdom},
}

@book{zhang2004changing,
title={The Changing Politics of Finance in Korea and Thailand: from deregulation to debacle},
author={Zhang, Xiaoke},
year={2004},
publisher={Routledge}
}

@book{satyanath2006globalization,
title={Globalization, politics, and financial turmoil},
author={Satyanath, Shanker},
year={2006},
publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge University Press}
}

@book{kohli2004state,
title={State-directed development: political power and industrialization in the global periphery},
author={Kohli, Atul},
year={2004},
publisher={Cambridge: Cambridge University Press}
}

@book{wade1990governing,
title={Governing the market: Economic theory and the role of government in East Asian industrialization},
author={Wade, Robert},
year={1990},
publisher={Princeton, New Jersey: Princeton University Press}
}
```

If I run the .tex file with the preamble above, everything is ok. My problem is that if I delete 10 or more in text citations (i.e. so that I have 35 or fewer \textcite citations in my .tex file), the problem as I described above shows up. That is, the 36th citation in my .bib file (currently von2010federal) has an intext citation is author (title) instead of author (year) and the same citation contains no year in the reference list.

I am beginning to think this is a bug of some kind. Everything seems so straightforward, yet the problem is so strange (to me at least). But any help or suggestions you or anyone else might have is of course greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Would you be able to reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem without including unnecessary code. It would be easier for anyone here to help. Also, when you speak about your `biblatex` file, you probably mean your `.bib`, right? (which can also be used by `bibtex`)

Comment: @Mike If it works with a different document, you might want to try the binary search method with the faulty one. Delete (or comment) half the document and see if the problem persist, if it does, go ahead and re-do the step; if it does not, re-add (or uncomment) the deleted part and investigate further by deleting (commenting) fewer lines. (You can and probably should also apply this technique to your `.bib` file). Thus, you isolate the problem and arrive at a truly minimal WE that we can have a look at.

Comment: @moewe I have updated my question to include a .tex file and a .bib file and a short description of my problem. I hope this is enough for a MWE.

Comment: When I run your example with `bibtex` I get all references in author/title format instead of author/year. If I run it with `biker` it works fine. I have tried with all your refs,  and a few ones. The `bibtex` log reports `Biblatex version: 2.1
Warning--Version mismatch: biblatex.bst=2.1, biblatex.sty=2.3` (and I have `biblatex 2.8`).

Answer (score 1):

When I run the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{altunbas2009turkish,
title={Turkish Banking: Banking Under Political Instability and Chronic High Inflation},
author={Altunbas, Yener and Kara, Alper and Olgu, Ozlem},
year={2009},
publisher={Palgrave Macmillan: United Kingdom},
}  
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\textcite{altunbas2009turkish}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

We get

[image]

Namely, in text references are printed with Author (title) format. The reasons for this is that recent biblatex versions look for `labelyear` field in building the citation, but when `bibtex` is used as backend, the field is not generated in the `.bbl` file, thus the field `labelyear` is undefined, and then `biblatex` resorts  to the `title` field.

Notice that there are warnings in the logs about the wrong version (both in the bibtex log and latex log)

A possible workaround is to force a definition of `labelyear`, including the following in the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\def\abx@field@labelyear{\thefield{year}}
\makeatother
```

This yields

[image]

**EDIT** The above solution does not work for older versions of biblatex.

A second alternative is to redefine the `citeyear` and `cite:labelyear+extrayear` bibmacros

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
       \printfield{year}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}

\newbibmacro*{citeyear}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\iffieldundef{year}
       {\bibstring{nodate}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

The second solution works for `\textcite`. More bibmacros and cite commands might need to be redefined.

Comment: I tried your workaround. For me, the in text citation has switched from author(title) to author(). The year has also disappeared in the reference list.

Comment: What version of `biblatex` do you have? In any case I would suggest to switch to `biber`.

Comment: I tried switching to biber a few months back. I couldnt get it to go. My     biblatex is 2.6.

Comment: The first solution works with `biblatex 2.8`. I would suggest to upgrade. One of the problem with `biber` is that one has to update both `biblatex` and `biber`.